# Indexing Additional Field with TTL in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, ttl

I want to index an additional field along with the TTL.
As mentioned in the docs, https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/index-ttl/#restrictions, MongoDB doesn't allow compund indexing with TTL.

" TTL indexes are a **single-field indexes**. Compound indexes do not support TTL and ignores the `expireAfterSeconds` option. "

Is there any hack by which I can make a compound index with TTL?

Comment: Just create a second, compound index that includes both columns.

Answer (score 0):

No, to my knowledge, there isn't. You can base the TTL index on an array, in which case the index will use the earliest date value to determine when to delete a document.